# wp_nav_menu() showing list in a different Position?

Tags: menus

While trying to add menu list as the following

```
<li>
 <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">

      <?php 
           wp_nav_menu(array(
               'theme_location' => 'header_menu_location',
               'echo' => false,
               'items_wrap' => '%3$s'
            ));

      ?>
                    
</div>
```

This function should show a list of items within div element but what I get is that list is being shown right after the outer li element. What's even weird about it is that when I do not use attribute 'items_wrap' the output is showing properly inside of the div container, only when I add to the args array the output list appears outside of its div container. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It's not working for two reasons.

1. You have `echo` set to false. This means it won't output anything unless you `echo` it manually.
2. The resulting HTML structure is invalid.

You have `items_wrap` set it `%3$s`. This means that the individual menu items, which are `<li>` tags, will be output without a wrapper. That would make the final structure this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

That's not valid HTML. The `<li>` tags need to be in an `<ol>` or `<ul>`, not a `<div>`. The simplest solution is to change the div to a `<ul>`:

```
<li>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">

      <?php 
           wp_nav_menu(array(
               'theme_location' => 'header_menu_location',
               'echo' => false,
               'items_wrap' => '%3$s'
            ));

      ?>
                    
</ul>
```